# Using php with google maps

Tags: php, html, mysql, google-maps

I'm just learning how to use the google maps with info from my database, and i'm having some trouble. I can get the map to appear with no problem, and the info from my database is being pulled correctly in the php page, but i can't seem to call that information in my html page. I'm trying to get little icons to appear on the map at each location in the database, but so far, nothing is appearing other than the google maps box. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

***googleMap.php***

```
<?
$username="myUsername";
$password="myPassword";
$database="myDatabase"; 
?> 

<?php

function parseToXML($htmlStr) 
{ 
$xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
$xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
return $xmlStr; 
} 

// Opens a connection to a MySQL server
$connection=mysql_connect (localhost, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active MySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$query = "SELECT * FROM markers";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
} 

// Start XML file, echo parent node


// Iterate through the rows, printing XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
// ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
echo 'marker ';
echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" ';
echo 'address="' . parseToXML($row['address']) . '" ';
echo 'lat="' . $row['lat'] . '" ';
echo 'lng="' . $row['lng'] . '" ';
echo 'type="' . $row['type'] . '" ';
echo '/>';
}
?>
```

**googleMap.html**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

var customIcons = {
  restaurant: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_blue.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  },
  bar: {
    icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png',
    shadow: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_shadow.png'
  }
};

function load() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(47.6145, -122.3418),
    zoom: 13,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

  downloadUrl(googleMap.php, function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
      var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
      var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
      var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
      var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
          parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point,
        icon: icon.icon,
        shadow: icon.shadow
      });
      bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
  });
}

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infoWindow.setContent(html);
    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  });
}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
  var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
      new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
      new XMLHttpRequest;

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
      request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
      callback(request, request.status);
    }
  };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="load()">
<div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
/body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have fiddle for people to play with?

Answer (score 0):

IN your PHP file you're echoing every row. But the markup is not correct. It should be a proper xml-node, you're displaying just some text.

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");

// Start XML file, create parent node
$doc = domxml_new_doc("1.0");
$node = $doc->create_element("markers");
$parnode = $doc->append_child($node);

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  // ADD TO XML DOCUMENT NODE
  $node = $doc->create_element("marker");
  $newnode = $parnode->append_child($node);

  $newnode->set_attribute("name", $row['name']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("address", $row['address']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("lat", $row['lat']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("lng", $row['lng']);
  $newnode->set_attribute("type", $row['type']);
}
```

See this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3#outputxml

Comment: Adding the "<" which you advised did not affect the displaying of the map. Also, before I added it, the php page correctly listed all the info (name, address, lat, etc...) when I opened it in the browser, but after adding the "<", nothing is on the php page when I view it in the browser

Comment: oh nvm you changed your answer completely haha

Comment: Yeah, but the stretch is the same. The fact you didn't saw anything in your browser adding the < is good! XML is a data-markup language; so it won't display something. Please read the link I provided in the _new_ answer! That tutorial is great!

Comment: haha thats actually the demo I was working off of, but I couldn't get it to work when I reciprocated it.

Comment: If you look at the code it _does_ have the < in front of the `marker`

Comment: yah i know, I originally had it like you suggested, but I couldn't get it to work. And when i removed the "<", i was able to see that I was echoing out the database info correctly

Comment: I literally copied it line for line (changing the database and url) and still can't get it to work and I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong.